# How do I print an array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Lets say I have an array of Object like :

```
var x=[{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}];
```

How do I print it just like as it is. So, it would be printed like

```
[{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}]
```

Comment: Dot matrix printer or line printer?

Comment: In FF they have `uneval`.

Answer (score 2):

You can always define your own `toString` method, but `JSON.stringify` will give you a close enough result:

```js
var x=[{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}];

alert(JSON.stringify(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `JSON.stringify(x)`

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

But if you just do this in order to debug, then you'd better use the console with `console.log(X)`.